# Wordpress site_url is different from database value

Tags: wordpress, ssl, https

I have a fresh Wordpress install that isn't loading the database `site_url` value properly. On the index, post permalinks are using `https`, but all assets (css, js, php files) are trying to load over `http`. As a result, no assets are loading and I can't even log in to the site as a result. When I try to login I get a warning about unsecured forms and the wp-admin login page just reloads.

I updated both `site_url` and `home` values in the database to be `https` but when I echo the `site_url` it's still `http`. Also, after I made this change, the `wp-admin` page won't load anymore, I get a re-direct loop error.

I've tried forcing SSL by adding the options in the `wp-config` file, but it doesn't fix it. I've followed every method for changing Site URL from [the Wordpress docs](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/), but this also didn't fix anything.

I've added a virtual host for port 80 as well, and it's working properly, but it didn't fix anything. I don't know if I have to add a Virtual Host for port 443 (I'm a front-end dev, not a server expert!). I feel like at this point I've gone through every similar Stack Overflow thread and tried everything there, but so far nothing has helped. It feels to me like the problem is at the server level, not Wordpress, but I might be wrong.

Comment: just confirming that you have flushed the permalinks?

Comment: @mikerojas yes, just tried that, no change after flushing.

Answer (score 0):

Has the URL been set by a constant in your wp-config.php?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed – after a ton of digging around, the issue was the fact that Wordpress is behind a load balancer (again, forgive my lack of server knowledge...)

Added the following to the `wp-config` file to fix the issue:

```
$_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] = 443;
```